# How to render component by adding the component using innerHTML?

Tags: html, angular

I have a component A which only contain a div with an id and a buttons that renders a component inside the div using innterHTML `document.getElementById('my-router-outlet').innerHTML = '<app-component-b-page></app-component-b-page>';`. But this is not rendering I wonder why?.

I'm trying to avoid using ngIf to be a selector for which component should be rendered for performance reason. Also if I clear the innerHTML does the resources of that component will be cleared?

Comment: I think the answer provided by @Smokey could work. If you need more suggestions, it would be great if you can provide a [demo](https://stackblitz.com) . Also, when you say performance, can you be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so a few things here

1. `innerHTML = '<app-component-b-page></app-component-b-page>'` is never going to work, angular wont recognise the angular component tag from a innerHTML call
2. using `*ngIf` wont affect the performance of the page, so doing the following

```
<app-component-b-page *ngIf="value === true"></app-component-b-page>
```

is probably you best option here

3. If you really don't want to use `*ngIf` you can use `@ViewChild` and `ComponentFactoryResolver`

In your HTML

```html
<!-- this is where your component will be rendered -->
<div #entry></div>
```

In your component

```js
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core'
import { YourComponent } from ... // import the component you want to inject 
// ...

export class ...
  @ViewChild('entry', {read: ViewContainerRef, static: true }) entry: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(
    private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  showComponent() {
     const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(YourComponent);
     // this will insert your component onto the page
     const component = this.entry.createComponent(factory);
  }

  // and if you want to dynamically remove the created component you can do this

  removeComponent() {
     this.entry.clear();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the element to the dom directly and it's not rendered by Angular.
You should go for the *ngIf.