# Initialize Angular component from inserted 3rd-party HTML

Tags: angular

I have `ComponentA` that uses a 3rd-party vanilla JavaScript plugin that generates HTML and inserts it into the DOM in the first `ngOnChanges()`. The HTML created by the plugin contains an element that matches the selector of `ComponentB`, but it isn't recognized or initialized as a `ComponentB` instance. How can I get Angular to recognize the inserted HTML as `ComponentB` and convert / initialize it?

I have tried all manner of Change Detection in all lifecycle hooks to no avail. I have also successfully used a MutationObserver to know when the HTML is inserted and used viewContainerRef to createComponent but that just creates a second, useless instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render component by adding the component using innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57505273/how-to-render-component-by-adding-the-component-using-innerhtml)

Comment: This also might help: https://medium.com/acute-angular/why-angular-does-not-support-rendering-dynamic-template-html-b8105328afd

Comment: @HarunYilmaz that SO does not answer my question. My problem has the added constraint of the unrecognized component HTML being generated by a 3rd-party plugin. And your second comment is what I feared...it may not be possible. :(

Comment: Actually it does. You say that the HTML contains something like `<app-component-b></app-component-b>` and you expect Angular to render it and create `ComponentB` instance, but it will not. Because Angular does not support this functionality.

Comment: Apologies for the misleading comment, @HarunYilmaz. `SO` in my comment above means `Stack Overflow`, not **so**.